# Vertx - Calling library which creates new thread

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2, vert.x, blocking

I am developing a RESTful API with Kotlin, Rx and Vert.x and I need to use a library which has a connection method where new threads are created.

I made some research in the code of the library and I saw that it can put threads to sleep, so I realize I need to call it with `.rxExecuteBlocking()` method, but my question is:

What is going to happen with new threads released by the library in Vertx? Taking into account the event loop pattern and so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should use worker verticles to execute blocking code. You can read more about it here:

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#worker_verticles

Then use `EventBus` to communicate with worker verticles. Make sure you're using `send()` and `reply()` mechanism for that.

Comment: You have both ways, using a worker verticle or using executeBlocking method. Anyway, I would want to know what is going to happen with new threads created inside that method.

Comment: My problem is "without any consequences". Thread by itself is a consequence, since it has quite a big memory footprint. And it also hard to control lifespan of a thread. But yeah, you can just `new Thread()`, and Vert.x won't be aware of that, nor will it break anything. Just make sure you don't `Thread.join()` on EventLoop thread.